# ReactJs Compiling Issue: immer.esm.js is not found

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am creating an reactJS application where I am using react-redux for state management. Few days back it was working fine but now I am getting below error at the time of compilation process:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/node_modules/immer/dist/immer.esm.js
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'root_directory\node_modules\@reduxjs\toolkit\node_modules\immer\dist\immer.esm.js'
```

I had setup react project using "create-react-app" command. After setting up, I have got few commands that I can use to run application. So, I am getting above issue while running below command:

```
npm run start
```

I have also tried to fix this issue after deleting package-lock.json file and then run npm install but still getting same error.

Can someone please guide me what has done wrongly and why this error arrived suddendly.

Thanks in advance